# working with ansi codes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, character-encoding, codepages

I have ran in to a problem while writing a program for school that converts a string like `abc` to `bcd`, `a` becomes `b` and `b` becomes `c` and you can see the rest.

```
For i = 0 To length - 1
    If (Asc(justatext.Substring(i, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(justatext.Substring(i, 1)) <= 90) Then
        Asc(justatext.Substring(i, 1) = (Asc(justatext.Substring(i, 1) + 1)))
        answer &= justatext.Substring(i, 1)
    End If
Next
```

This is in a function and I return the value `answer`, but I always get an `invalid cast exception`. Is there a way you can do this with `ansi` codes?.

Comment: i put words in that don't contain the letter "z" so that should not be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem can be found in the brackets, you have quite a lot of them, and I think you confused yourself with them.

I've tripped down your code and removed the brackets that aren't needed:

```
    For i = 0 To justatext.Length - 1
        If Asc(justatext.Substring(i, 1)) >= 65 And Asc(justatext.Substring(i, 1)) <= 90 Then
            answer &= Chr(Asc(justatext.Substring(i, 1)) + 1)
        End If
    Next
```

Watch out: this code will only work for capital letters..

Comment: thanks a lot! but if a but in the string "AAA" now my output in the textbox I retrun the value to is 666666 (the ansi-code itself) thanks for the reply!

Comment: @larsvdb97 There you go, enjoy the code! (Watch out, only works with capital letters!)

Comment: yeah i know, just gonna add a inf statement to make it work for lowercase letter as well ;) thank a ton!